# What is the correct way to define a BaseActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, abstract, radix

This Question i specific to `Android` and the use of a Base `Activity` that can be extended by all other Activities. In general w.r.t Java i understand the use and functioning of `abstract classes`. I my case i have a Base Activity with some common constants ,functions and implements some `Interfaces`. My Question is should it be `abstract` or can i leave it as a normal `Activity`. Is there a specific reason for it to be `abstract`.

```
//Standard BaseActivity 
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
   //common code
}

//Usage 
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {
}
```

This also seems to work if i defined BaseActivity as follows

```
//Non Abstract Class
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
}
```

Hence the question is there a specific reason to use abstract.
In both cases i dont define the BaseActivity in Manifest.

Comment: you need to read some java again :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680880/java-unique-difference-between-abstract-class-and-concrete-class

https://www.javatpoint.com/q/4915/what-is-difference-between-normal-class-and-abstract-class-and-interface

and yes you can use both as according to your reqirements.

Comment: have look [BaseActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8821459/5110595)

Comment: @Umair i ad already looked at the link provided , i have updated my question with a little more description.

Comment: @Hemant Parmar  that is not what i was asking , i have updated my question a little.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can refer the following way for defining a BaseActivity.**

> It’s always been a good idea to make a baseActivity in android
>   project.

What, I am suggesting is to create an activity from android.app.Activity called baseActivity and make the 3 custom activity to extend from baseActivity.

*For example,*

```
public abstract class MyAppBaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

*And your custom activity*

```
public class MyCustomActivity extends MyAppBaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

**Notice that**, MyAppBaseActivity is an abstract class. The reason is, we are not going to instantiate it. That’s why you don’t need to add the MyAppBaseActivity class in AndroidManifest.xml file.

> Now the question is, why would you do that? Means, why you need to
>   make an baseActivity class and then make your other activities as a
>   subclass of it?

*Well, here are few very generic reasons*

**1.** You can avoid code duplication of you application wise common ui tasks. Suppose you want to show progressDialog in different activities. Just write code to show a progressDialog in your baseActivity and call that method from other activity.

**2.** Your application menu should be consistent across different application. For example, you have a settings screen. Option menu is containing the navigation to settings screen. You should display the settings throughout the application, means regardless of activity. User want to access the settings screen from anywhere in application. This feature can be easily achieved, but you have to override onCreateOptionsMenu in each of your activity or, you can override it once in your baseActivity.

Comment: I understand this , what i am asking is all this happens even when i use regular class instead of abstract class for the BaseActivity . So is there any fundemental reason to use abstract class.

Comment: @Deepak Abstract classes may not be instantiated, and require sub-classes to provide implementations for the abstract methods. That's the reason behind I have defined class as an Abstract